# Solve the following PDE: $(1+\sqrt{z-y-x})z'_x+z'_y=2$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Solve the following PDE: $(1+\sqrt{z-y-x})z'_x+z'_y=2$ given that $z(x,2x)=2x$.

I want to explain to you how we were taught to solve these at class, and this method seemed to work with other exercises, but with this one it seems to fail.

We rewrite the question:

$\frac{d x}{1+\sqrt{z-y-x}}=\frac{d y}{1}=\frac{d z}{2}$

We can see that $2dy=dz$, so $2y-z=C_1$ where $C_1$ is some constant. We define the function $\psi_1(x,y,z)=2y-z$. We called this function "An integral of the system". We need to find another one. We can see that

$dz=2dy, dy=dy, dx=(1+\sqrt{z-y-x})dy$, and so $dz-dy-dx=-\sqrt{z-y-x}dy$

Divide to get $\frac{dz-dy-dx}{-\sqrt{z-y-x}}=\frac{d(z-y-x)}{-\sqrt{z-y-x}}=dy$

Integrate to get the second integral, $y+2\sqrt{z-y-x}=C_2$, let's call it $\psi_2(x,y,z)=y+2\sqrt{z-y-x}$. So now we have our 2 integrals $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$.

For our method to work, we need to apply the initial value to our integrals, meaning find $\psi_1(x,2x,z)$ and $\psi_2(x,2x,z)$. Let's call them $\bar\psi_1$ and $\bar \psi_2$ respectively.

So $psi_1(x,2x,z)=4x-z=\bar \psi_1$ and $\psi_2(x,2x,z)=2x+2\sqrt{z-3x}=\bar \psi_2$

We can now (in theory, that's what worked in previous exercises) represent $x$ and $z$ as functions of $\bar \psi_1$ and $\bar \psi_2$: $x=f(\bar \psi_1,\bar \psi_2)$ and $z=g(\bar \psi_1,\bar \psi_2)$

Now the final step to get the solution, we apply that to the initial value: $z(x,2x)=2x$, but $x=f(\bar \psi_1,\bar \psi_2)$ and $z=g(\bar \psi_1,\bar \psi_2)$

And so:

$g(\bar \psi_1,\bar \psi_2)=2f(\bar \psi_1, \bar \psi_2)$ and plugging in $g(\psi_1,\psi_2)=2f(\psi_1,\psi_2)$ we can find either an explicit or an implicit term for $z$.

There is no doubt that this method works, as it solved all of our other exercises, but in this one, I'm having trouble representing $x$ and $z$ as functions of $\bar \psi_1$ and $\bar \psi_2$.

We know that $z=4x-\bar \psi_1$, which would mean $2x+2\sqrt{4x-\bar \psi_1-3x}=\bar \psi_2$ and I wasn't able to extract an explicit term for $x$ from that equation.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the method in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example:

$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=1$ , letting $y(0)=0$ , we have $y=t$

$\dfrac{dz}{dt}=2$ , letting $z(0)=z_0$ , we have $z=z_0+2t=z_0+2y$

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=1+\sqrt{z-y-x}=1+\sqrt{z_0+t-x}$

Let $u=z_0+t-x$ ,

Then $x=z_0+t-u$

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=1-\dfrac{du}{dt}$

$\therefore1-\dfrac{du}{dt}=1+\sqrt u$

$-\dfrac{du}{dt}=\sqrt u$

$dt=-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt u}~du$

$t=f(z_0)-2\sqrt u$

$y=f(z-2y)-2\sqrt{z-y-x}$

Case $1$: $z(x,y=2x)=2x$ :

$2x=f(-2x)-2\sqrt{-x}$

$f(-2x)=2\sqrt{-x}+2x$

$f(x)=\sqrt{2x}-x$

$\therefore y=\sqrt{2z-4y}+2y-z-2\sqrt{z-y-x}$

Case $2$: $z(y=x,2x)=2x$ :

Consider $z=2y+F(2\sqrt{z-y-x}+y)$ :

$2x=2x+F(2\sqrt{-x}+x)$

$F(2\sqrt{-x}+x)=0$

$F(x)=0$

$\therefore z=2y$